# Oh you, I need in every second

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

You fill all earths emptiness
The higher I go, you get less

If you go away nobody will stay
The jellyfish might still play

Oh I, representative of all being
Oh I, just you I will keep needing

Oh you, not visible but irreplaceable
Oh you, so essential but untraceable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess the "you" in the riddle must be

> Air

You fill all earths emptiness

> The atmosphere of Earth is the layer of gases, commonly known as air, that surrounds the planet Earth.

The higher I go, you get less

> The atmosphere becomes thinner and thinner with increasing altitude, with no definite boundary between the atmosphere and outer space.

If you go away nobody will stay

> Most animals need oxygen to survive.

The jellyfish might still play.

> Jellyfish can absorb the oxygen in water although there is an [animal](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20170125-there-is-one-animal-that-seems-to-survive-without-oxygen) that looks a bit like a jellyfish and can survive without oxygen.

Oh I, representative of all being

> The "I" in the riddle must represent life in general or possibly the life that exists on land.

Oh I, just you I will keep needing

> All land animals need air to survive

Oh you, not visible but irreplaceable

> Air is invisible.

Oh you, so essential but untraceable

> The one shortcoming of this answer is that air is not entirely untraceable but at least hard to track and predict.

Comment: In terms of traceability, your answer is still on point because:
_spoilers_ (no spoiler markdown in comments aye?)
>! if we replace air with O2, and look at it from a carbon dating perspective, O2 is not traceable, unlike CO2 which adds carbon making it traceable - which also ties in with the Jellyfish that can survive on high levels of CO2 (as they are better adapted for this) unlike O2 which better favors fish, so I believe if we extend air to O2, it fits perfectly

Comment: Or ozone. Fits for line 2,3,4. For 7,8 it is very good. Unfortunately not good for line 1.

Comment: Yes well done! I guess it was a bit too easy.